# Exception Safety example guarantee correct?

Tags: c++, exception-safe, exception-safety

I discuss the **Exception Safety Guaratees** and devised an example that I think provides the **Strong Guarantee**:

```
template<typename E, typename LT>
void strongSort(vector<E*> &data, LT lt) // works on pointers
{
  vector<E*> temp { data };  // bad_alloc? but 'data' not changed. 
  sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), lt); // 'lt' might throw!
  swap(temp, data); // considered safe.
}
```

Just an easy (C++0x)-example how this is used:

```
int main() {
  vector<int*> data { new int(3), new int(7), new int(2), new int(5) };
  strongSort( data, [](int *a, int *b){ return *a<*b;} );
  for(auto e : data) cout << *e << " ";
}
```

Assuming `LT` does not change the elments, but it may throw. Is it correct to assume thiat the code provides

- the **Strong Exception Safety** guarantee
- Is **Exception Neutral**, w.r.t to `LT`

Comment: I would do away with using pointers within the vector, they make things awkward for no real benefit. `std::vector<int>` would illustrate your point as well, and save you from memory leaks.

Comment: Well, yes. `int` is a bad example, I should have done this with `Image`. And then, I agree with *jagansai* below, I should use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: not necessarily (the resource is not shared) a `unique_ptr` would do well (if you have C++0x)

Comment: This would break the point of my example, where I want to show the *copy-work-swap*-Idiom for the **strong exception safe guarantee**  With the `unique_ptr` one can not copy, only move. Therefore, if anything goes wrong in the `LT`-oepration, the strong exception guarantee is broken.

Comment: right... the resource is shared because of an implementation detail. Perhaps that the right fix would be to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Image>>` to store the images, and supplement it by a `std::vector<Image*>`, that would serve as an index, and then sort the index, not the content holder. (I don't like `shared_ptr` much, shared ownership is *usually* an indication of a faulty design).

Comment: I think we are on the same page. I would not go so far to say I dont *like* `shared_ptr`, but the question "who owns this thing" should be answered in a clear manner. So, I like `shared_ptr` (for the owner) together with `weak_ptr` (for the users), or as a quick-and-dirty solution `unique_ptr` (for the owner) together with Raw Pointers (the users).

Comment: I agree that the `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` is extremely clean, especially as it avoids stale pointer issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Strong exception guarantee means that the operation completes successfully or leaves the data unchanged.

Exception neutral means that you let the exceptions propagate.

Answer (score 0):

It is exception safe. To be more safe, why not use `vector<shared_ptr<int>>`

```
template<typename Type, typename Func>
void StrongSort( vector<shared_ptr<Type>>& elems, Func fun)
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Type>> temp ( elems.begin(), elems.end());
    sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), fun);
    swap(elems, temp);
}

vector<shared_ptr<int>> ints;
ints.push_back(shared_ptr<int>(new int(3)));
ints.push_back(shared_ptr<int>(new int(1)));
ints.push_back(shared_ptr<int>(new int(2)));
StrongSort(ints, [](shared_ptr<int> x, shared_ptr<int> y) -> bool { return *x < *y; });
```

Comment: two reasons: a) in my tutorial I have not covered `shared_ptr` at that point. b) shared_ptr comes with more runtime overhead. there is no real "share semantics" here, so no need for `shared_ptr`. But you could convince me to using `unique_ptr` -- they should come for free, but may render the example useless, because I can not make a copy of a vector of them ;-)

Comment: True. shared_ptr comes with an overhead. I was just trying to say, if you are using objects in place of primitive types, it's more safer to use "vector of shared_ptrs" instead of vector of pointers.